# How to indicate type on the flight in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I would like to know if there is a way to mark a variable to a specific type in a script case without defining a new variable for the TS compiler ? I'm treating this as RoleCard with the "as" but i would like to not define a var

```typescript
const card = this.deck.shift();

switch (card.type) {
  case CardType.ROLE:
    const roleCard = card as RoleCardMeta;

    const activeCard: ActiveCard = {
      remainingTurns: _.random(roleCard.minTurns, roleCard.maxTurns),
      roleCard,
    };
    this.activeCards.push();
    break;
}
```

Best regards

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, since you haven't posted code that compiles as-is.  When I filled in missing pieces, I see that TypeScript narrows `card` to `RoleCardMeta` automatically without needing a new variable.  Please post a [mcve] so someone can help you.

Comment: it looks like you would need typeguards. look into that :)

Comment: Typeguards looks good, but it seems they force me to add some runtime code with the isX(), the thing is I don't really need to check, I already know what type i've it just want to tell it to the compiler. :)

So i used to following syntax : (card as RoleCardMeta).minTurns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use type guards on `type` literal and union types:

```
interface CardBase {
    someField: any;
}

enum CardType {
    ROLE,
    OTHER
}

interface RoleCardMeta extends CardBase {
    type: CardType.ROLE;
    minTurns: number;
    maxTurns: number;
}

interface OtherCardMeta extends CardBase {
    type: CardType.OTHER;
    otherField: string;
}

type Card = RoleCardMeta
    | OtherCardMeta;

function test(card: Card) {
    switch (card.type) {
        case CardType.ROLE:
            console.log(card.minTurns, card.maxTurns);
            break;

        case CardType.OTHER:
            console.log(card.otherField);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Literal Type Guard did the job ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I almost had the same than you @oryol but I had to add the following to make it work:

```
case CardType.STANDARD:
    return {
      remainingTurns: _.random((card as MessageCardMeta).minTurns, (card as MessageCardMeta).maxTurns),
    }
```

Comment: TypeScript is able to automatically detect type in this case. Could you please post complete code?

Comment: Compare it with my code. Include `type: CardType.Something` into each inherited card interface definition. In such case explicit casting will not be required

Comment: All right, I didn't know I could do that, that's why I didn't understand ^^ Thats huge. Thank you